# how to implement bidimensional array where each element has a set of values in python?

Tags: python

I have a problem implementing the following in python:

I have a nxn matrix like this:

```
[ X11 X12 X13 ... x1n

Xn1 Xn2 Xn3 ... Xnn  ]
```

Thats simple to get but any of those "Xij" values has 4 simple int values(0 or 1 each) and i cant seem to understand how to create an array or collection that i can use.

Does anyone know what is the best solution to this scenario?

Perhaps creating an object to store 4 int numbers and then creating a bidimensional array that contains them but i want the "best" approach to this problem.

Im using numpy and python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just a three-dimensional array, that is, an array of arrays of arrays, where the innermost array contains four elements, and the outer two arrays are your matrix?

Comment: Also, i'd use numpy or scipy to store them, instead of python's native list or array.

Comment: Because with numpy accessing an element from this deep 4-tuple will be easier.  you can say x[:,:,0] to get an 2-d array of first element of your 4-tuple.  I guess my comment is mere suggestion, not necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Why not package the integers into a tuple? Then you would have a bidimensional array in the form:

```
[[(1,0,0,1),   (1,1,1,0),   (0,0,0,1)],
 [(1,0,0,0),   (0,1,1,0),   (0,1,0,1)]]
```

The tuple is good because it is light-weight (compared to the object); further, it is more conventional to use a tuple if each integer in the group of 4 has a specific meaning, i.e. the first integer means something different from the third.

Comment: perhaps it could be a list, as a tuple is no good for this case, its inmmutable and i would need to change those values. anyway i think im going for the 3-dimensional array. thks for answering